# How to de-OP players by using command blocks

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I de-OP players by using Command Blocks instead of chat commands?

The chat commands are easier, but I want to know how do it using a *Command Block*, I also would like to know if the `/op` command will work.

Comment: What would the purpose of this be? A chat command would be much easier AFAIK.\

Comment: I just wanna know, I also wanna know how do I do op command in the command block so I could open myself whenever my admin friend drop me (sorry if I have spelling mistakes, I'm from Israel and my English is not that good)

Comment: And when I try to do those command it doesnt works

Comment: Don't worry about the spelling mistakes in the question. We have edit functions for a reason. Just stick around and answer any questions as they pop up to clarify.

Comment: Like I did just now :D

Comment: AFAIK op commands are disabled with command blocks (Last I checked was 5-6 months ago), so it won't be possible without some sort of mod.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You cannot.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Command_Block#Notes)

There are various commands that are unavailable, probably due to the ability for abuse (such as reopping yourself after having your admin privileges revoked).

This list currently includes: ban, banlist, ban-ip, debug, *deop*, kick, *op*, pardon, pardon-ip, publish, save-all, save-off, save-on, stop and whitelist.